# No geometry value provided at geodjango admin

Tags: django-admin, geodjango

I'm trying geodjango for my pet project and everything looks good with an exception...

In my model I have a field like this:

```
coordinates= models.PointField(srid=4326,default='POINT(0.0 0.0)')
```

and my admin extends from `admin.OSMGeoAdmin` but when I open a new model instance in the admin, I'm not seeing the '0.00,0.00' point selected in the map and if I try to save the document, I'll get 'No geometry value provided'. Like if the admin just Can't put the point in the map.

Also, if I try using the shell, I can save instances w/o problem and get the field with the default value POINT(0.0 0.0).

Am I missing something in the admin?

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after toying around with open layers.html (THANKS noisyboiler!) I found there is an attribute on the OSMGeoAdmin `display_wkt`, setting it to `True` will show the textArea without hacking the template.

For entries with existing points, it contains a value in this format:

```
SRID=3857;POINT(890338.8453418 -1109499.0330941)
```

So I just change my Point Field to:

```
coordinates= models.PointField(srid=4326,default='SRID=3857;POINT(0.0 0.0)')
```

What I understand from [Spherical Mercator](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html) is that 4326 is for two-dimensional maps, but seems like google Maps uses 3857 which includes a spherical projection.

Now works!

Comment: @Billi Tobon Where exactly do you add "the OSMGeoAdmin display_wkt, setting it to True" I am having the exact same problem

Comment: ok got it I go on the admin page where `admin.site.register(Member, admin.OSMGeoAdmin)` I highlight `OSMGeoAdmin` right-click and choose implementation. This is for PyCharm may be different for different editors

Comment: @Billi Tobon I changed my models to the below but its not working for me: 

`class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    image = models.ImageField()
    lat = models.FloatField()
    lon = models.FloatField()
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326, default='SRID=3857;POINT(0.0 0.0)')
    objects = models.GeoManager()


`

Is there anything else that you changed

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. 
It's weird. What is getting POSTed makes no sense.
At the point of hitting submit the textarea has the correct geometry value (as I put an onsubmit on the form that outputs me this value).
But what gets submitted is not that value.
So I turned JS off... wow. The correct value is submitted and I am a little happier, but this is not a solution.
But what javascript is doing this I don't know.
I've tried this with Django 1.3 and 1.4.
Have you had any luck?

update. one more 'solution'... override openlayers.html and turn the textarea to a standard text input. wow. works again.

SOLVED!

So mine took some digging... but my admin uses tinymce... Tinymce works on textareas yeah.... well it screwed up the widgets textarea, but ever so silently.

editor_deselector : "vWKTField"